# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot use Airtel 4G LTE dongle

Tags: 16.04, networking

Up until yesterday things seemed fine with accessing the internet. However after a restart, I am not able to connect to the internet using a dongle. The dongle is a Airtel 4G LTE.
The network is not shown in the settings.

I tried restarting my system and also the NetworkManager, but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Have you done an update recently? What drivers do you have?

Comment: Yes i did an update recently. I currently have ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on my system. Kernel driver in use is i915

Comment: Did it break after the update?

Comment: Try  booting Ubuntu with an older kernel from grub. That might work.

Comment: Update was successful. I don't exactly remember if it stopped working after the update. The wifi icon does not show the "connect to airtel" option